# Error when giving a specific number in listView flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I give a specific number in the listView itemCount, it works as intended, but before loading, it gives an error. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks. This is the code that I am using. This is the error message that is given -> NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried Calling . However This error is not given when i use the snapshot.data.length.

```
child: FutureBuilder(

                    future: data, //was getData() so if there are any errors change this and the PROBLEM WILL BE FIXED
                    builder: (context,
                        snapshot) { // getting items = snapshot.data[0]['Title']
                      try{
                        return ListView.separated(
                            separatorBuilder:(context, index) => Divider(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ) ,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                            
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                return Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                      offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75),
                                      blurRadius: 7,
                                  ),
                                  ]
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade300, width: 1.3),
                                                                      
                                  ),
                                  child: NewsButton(
                                    snapshot.data[index]['Image'],
                                    snapshot.data[index]['Title'],
                                    connectivity,
                                    snapshot.data[index]['Link'],
                                    context
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                      } catch(exception){
                        checkConnection(context);
                        print(exception);
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();


                        }
                      }

                ) // getJson()
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there

when you give it a specific number at first snapshot has no data so basically its data is null and when you write

```
snapshot.data[index]['Link']
```

data is null and you call [index] on null, and after fetching the data, error is gone because the data isn't null anymore.

However when you use snapshot data length it has no error because when the data is null the length is zero and when the data is fetched the data is updated and so as itemCount.

For your case just check if the data is empty if it is give the itemcount zero if not give your desired number

Answer (score 0):

try this one hope it work for you.

```
child: FutureBuilder(

                    future: data, //was getData() so if there are any errors change this and the PROBLEM WILL BE FIXED
                    builder: (context,
                        snapshot) { // getting items = snapshot.data[0]['Title']
                      try{
                        return snapshot.sna.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),) 
                        : ListView.separated(
                            separatorBuilder:(context, index) => Divider(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ) ,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                            
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                return Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                      offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75),
                                      blurRadius: 7,
                                  ),
                                  ]
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade300, width: 1.3),
                                                                      
                                  ),
                                  child: NewsButton(
                                    snapshot.data[index]['Image'],
                                    snapshot.data[index]['Title'],
                                    connectivity,
                                    snapshot.data[index]['Link'],
                                    context
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                      } catch(exception){
                        checkConnection(context);
                        print(exception);
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();


                        }
                      }

                ) // getJson()
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your response. The code I used to fix this, is

```
child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 5),
                child: FutureBuilder(

                    future: data, //was getData() so if there are any errors change this and the PROBLEM WILL BE FIXED
                    builder: (context,
                        snapshot) { // getting items = snapshot.data[0]['Title']
                      try{
                        int connection_check;
                        if(snapshot.data.length == null || snapshot.data.length == "")
                          connection_check = 0;
                        else
                          connection_check = 20;

                        return ListView.separated(
                            separatorBuilder:(context, index) => Divider(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ) ,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                            
                            itemCount: connection_check,
```